# symmetric matrix vector multiplication combined modules

Tags: performance, fortran, fortran90, memory-efficient, linear-equation

Written two modules:

1. conjugate gradient method
2. band matrix-vector multiplication

they work separately (with machine error difference due to addition nonassociativity being around 1e-14 to 1e-15)

But when combined I cant track the reason for the error. The results between regular matrix vector multiplication and using my module `matVecMult` differ significantly.

Could one suggest where the issue may be coming from?

Modules, vector, matricies are below:

a) dense banded matrix [dnsa](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10pHu-kiyxelKv3zuE6REHKZXkM9Rx1L_/view?usp=sharing)

b) sparse matrix [a](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q500lJRz12Fz45apIaN5V12rxniwIR8k/view?usp=sharing)

c) vector of non-zero diagonals indicies

```
cols = [1 2 3 4 5 6 9]
```

d) CG solver

```
module LinSolver
    use denseTimesVec
    implicit none
    contains
    subroutine cg(a,dnsa,n,b,cols,x)
        implicit none
        integer*8, intent (in) :: n
        real*8, intent (in) :: a(:,:)
        real*8, intent (in) :: dnsa(:,:)
        real*8, intent (inout):: b(:)
        real*8, intent (out) :: x(:)
        integer*8, intent (in) :: cols(:)


        ! local variables
        integer :: i, j, k
        real*8, dimension(n) :: r, p, Ap, ApDNS
        real*8, parameter :: eps = 1.e-6
        real*8 :: rsold, rsnew, alpha, pAp

        call matVecMult(n,dnsa,x,cols,ApDNS)
        do i = 1,n
            Ap(i) = 0
            do j = 1,n
                Ap(i) = Ap(i) + a(i,j) * x(j)
            enddo
        enddo
        print*,cols

        r = b - Ap
        p = r

        rsold = 0;
        do j = 1,n
            rsold = rsold + r(j)*r(j);
        enddo
        
        
        do i=1,n
            call matVecMult(n,dnsa,p,cols,ApDNS)
            do k = 1,n
                Ap(k) = 0;
                do j = 1,n
                    Ap(k) = Ap(k) + A(k,j) * p(j);
                enddo
            enddo
            
            pAp = 0;
            do j = 1,n
                pAp = pAp + Ap(j) * p(j);
            enddo
            alpha = rsold / pAp;
            x = x + alpha * p;
            r = r - alpha * Ap;
            rsnew = 0;
            do j = 1,n
                rsnew = rsnew + r(j)*r(j);
            enddo
            if (sqrt(rsnew)<eps) exit
            p = r + (rsnew / rsold) * p
            rsold = rsnew
        enddo
    end subroutine cg
end module LinSolver
```

e) multiplication module

```
module denseTimesVec
    
    implicit none
    contains
    subroutine matVecMult(n,a,x,cols,b)
    
    implicit none        
    integer*8, intent (in) :: n
    real*8, intent (out) :: b(:)
    real*8, intent (in):: a(:,:), x(:)
    integer*8, intent (in) :: cols(:)
    integer*8   ::  i, j, width
    real*8, dimension (:), allocatable :: xTimesUpper, xTimesLower
    
    allocate ( xTimesUpper(n), xTimesLower(n)) 
    
    
    do j = 1,size(cols)
        width = cols(j)-1;
        do i = 1,n-width
            if (width == 0) then
                b(i) = b(i)+a(i,1)*x(i);
            else
                xTimesUpper = x(1+width:n);
                xTimesLower = x(1:n-width);
                
                ! multiplying upper/lower part
                b(i) = b(i) + a(i,j) * xTimesUpper(i); ! OK if compared to triuA*x-b
                b(i+width) = b(i+width) + a(i,j)*xTimesLower(i);
            endif
        enddo
    enddo
    
    end subroutine matVecMult
    
    end module denseTimesVec
```

Comment: What error?  And where's the [mcve]?